# Swift 2.0: Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x10a9348d8) to 'NSDictionary' (0x10a934d60)

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift2, nsdictionary

I have been reading some of the responses to questions with similar problems but I just can't figure it out...

I have PostService that does a JSON POST request and fetches the data from a MySQL database. Everything was working before I did the conversion to Swift 2.0 and now it's giving me gears. (Code comes from Skip Wilson's Youtube series - [Swift: Using External Databases and API's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FYElY4ewq_o))

It gives the above error in the output and stops and highlights this line -

> "let response = (try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSDictionary"

```
var settings:Settings!

init() {
    self.settings = Settings()
}

let userLoginEmail = "admin@email.co.za"; 
let userLoginPassword = "1234";            

func getPosts(callback:(NSDictionary) -> ()) {
    request(settings.viewPosts, callback: callback) 
}

func request(url:String, callback:(NSDictionary) -> ()) {

    let myURL = NSURL(string: url)
    let requested = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myURL!);
    requested.HTTPMethod = "POST";

    let postString = "email=\(userLoginEmail)&password=\(userLoginPassword)";

    print("email=\(userLoginEmail)&password=\(userLoginPassword)")

    requested.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(requested) {
        (data, response, error) in

   let response = (try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSDictionary

        callback(response)
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Here's my JSON post... With my limited knowledge and reading up on json.org, it looks like an object with an array inside it containing a bunch of objects (A dictionary?) The format of all of this did not change and my app would fetch the data from the database and display it correctly before the conversion..

```
{"posts":[{"Post":{"Id":"5","idno":"4","product":"Aspen Simvastatin","quantity":"30","due_date":"2015-04-11","last_repeat":"2015-04-10","doctor":"Dr. Jim Jones","store":"Central","currentrepeat":"2","totalrepeat":"6","active_ingredient":"Simvastatin","strength":"20mg","manufacturer":"Aspen Pharmacare","dosage_form":"Tabs","directions":"Take one tablet daily","repeatflag":"0","repeattimestamp":"2015-08-17 20:38:13"}},{"Post":{"Id":"6","idno":"4","product":"Mybulen","quantity":"45","due_date":"2015-04-11","last_repeat":"2015-04-10","doctor":"Dr. Jim Jones","store":"Central","currentrepeat":"3","totalrepeat":"6","active_ingredient":"Codeine Phosphate;Ibuprofen;Paracetamol","strength":"10mg;200mg;250mg","manufacturer":"Aspen Pharmacare","dosage_form":"Tabs","directions":"Take one or two tablets four times a day after meals","repeatflag":"0","repeattimestamp":"2015-08-17 20:38:13"}},{"Post":{"Id":"7","idno":"4","product":"Ecotrin XL","quantity":"30","due_date":"2015-04-11","last_repeat":"2015-03-11","doctor":"Dr. Jim Jones","store":"Central","currentrepeat":"4","totalrepeat":"6","active_ingredient":"Aspirin","strength":"81mg","manufacturer":"Litha Pharma","dosage_form":"Tabs","directions":"Take one tablet in the morning","repeatflag":"0","repeattimestamp":"2015-08-17 20:38:13"}},{"Post":{"Id":"8","idno":"4","product":"Lorien","quantity":"28","due_date":"2015-04-11","last_repeat":"2015-03-11","doctor":"Dr. J. Eckel","store":"Central","currentrepeat":"4","totalrepeat":"6","active_ingredient":"Fluoxetine HCl","strength":"20mg","manufacturer":"Aspen Pharmacare","dosage_form":"Caps","directions":"Take one capsule in the morning","repeatflag":"0","repeattimestamp":"2015-08-17 20:38:13"}}]}
```

I would be extremely grateful for any help on this.

In my masterViewController's viewDidLoad(), I have this code which process the information fetched...

```
      service = PostService()
    service.getPosts {
        (response) in
        self.loadPosts(response["posts"]! as! NSArray)
    }

}

func loadPosts(posts:NSArray) {
    for post in posts {
        let post = post["Post"]! as! NSDictionary
        let Id = Int((post["Id"]! as! String))!
        let idno = Int((post["idno"]! as! String))!
        let product = post["product"]! as! String
        let quantity = Int((post["quantity"]! as! String))!
        let doctor = post["doctor"]! as! String
        let store = post["store"]! as! String
        let currentrepeat = Int((post["currentrepeat"]! as! String))!
        let totalrepeat = Int((post["totalrepeat"]! as! String))!
        let active_ingredient = post["active_ingredient"]! as! String
        let strength = post["strength"]! as! String
        let manufacturer = post["manufacturer"]! as! String
        let dosage_form = post["dosage_form"]! as! String
        let directions = post["directions"]! as! String
        let postObj = Post(Id: Id, idno: idno, product: product, quantity: quantity, doctor: doctor, store: store, currentrepeat: currentrepeat, totalrepeat: totalrepeat, active_ingredient: active_ingredient, strength: strength, manufacturer: manufacturer, dosage_form: dosage_form, directions: directions)
        postsCollection.append(postObj)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Comment: The highlighted line doesn't appear in the code you posted?!?

Comment: Thanks @trojanfoe - must have cut instead of copy..

Comment: Are you *certain* that's the JSON you are attempting to process?

Comment: The error message says, the result is an array, not a dictionary

Comment: @trojanfoe Yes. Just added the bit of code in my masterViewController that shows what it does with it...

Comment: @vadian What I don't understand is the with Swift 1.0, before the conversion, it worked... Would I just replace all instances of NSDictionary with NSArray?

Comment: No... are you certain the JSON you posted is actually what you're receiving?  For example perhaps a different structure is returned on error or some such.

Comment: I'm so embarrassed... It was looking at the wrong PHP url...
Thanks so much... @trojanfoe

Comment: I'm just reading the error message and the compiler is never wrong in those cases.

Comment: @trojanfoe: Of course he is _certain_ that this is the JSON he's trying to process. The question isn't whether he is certain, the question is whether it's true.

Comment: @gnasher729 He has already acknowledged that the data he is getting is not what he posted, so he is not certain.  Thanks for playing.

Answer (score 2):

You are telling NSJSONSerialization that you are absolutely sure that the JSON can be parsed and that you want your app to crash if it doesn't. (That's the try! ). Well, there are plenty of situations where you are asking for JSON and you are getting html back, so your users won't be happy with that, let's say if they use your app in a hotel or at the nearest starbucks.

Next, you are telling NSJSONSerialization that you are absolutely sure that the JSON contains a dictionary, and that you want your app to crash if it doesn't (as! NSDictionary). Guess what, you were given an array. You better read the documentation for your API, and check what you are given here.

BTW. I don't care what you are posting what JSON you are supposedly getting - I *know* that you received an array. Don't believe it? First rule of debugging: What you know is wrong.